# Are there any plugins or modules like Django flatpages for Java in Spring?

Tags: java, django, spring

Current I use Django and Python for web development.

I know Java, [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework), and [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) but not to an advanced level.

My main aim is to build a website with user registration and some static pages.

Now in Django, the flat pages modules are best for static pages and this is most commonly used.

Is there anything like that which I can use in Java with Spring? So that I don't have to code. Because I find it very hard to code the whole administration section for simple websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to serve up static pages would be to create a simple Controller that has a basic `ReqestMapping` which takes a `PathVariable`.  Create static pages for each identifier and let the Controller serve them up.  As follows:

```
@Controller
public class StaticPagesController {
  @RequestMapping("/static/{id}/view.do")
  public String subscribersListingHandler(@PathVariable String id) {
     return id;
  }
}
```

In the above, `id` is the name of the JSP file.  Example call: `http://myapp.com/static/about/view.do`.